# Subgroup decomposition from group decompostion

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite, non-abelian group, $Q,H,K$ be some strict subgroups of $G$ and $G = HK$. When the result $Q = \left(Q \cap H \right) \left(Q \cap K \right)$ is true?

For example, if one of $H$ or $K$ is contained in $Q$ this results by Dedekind modularity law.

Another example is when $H$ and $K$ are normal and $Q$ is a sylow subgroup of $G$.

Are there any other results? For example if $Q$ be a special subgroup such as center, derivation, normalizer, etc? Or $G$ have some properties such as solvability, p-group, etc? Or $H,K$ have some properties such as normality?

Comment: No thats not. That question was a special case of this.

Comment: Here I give some example to clear what I mean. that question was unconditioned but here condition is acceptable.

Comment: I've retracted my down- and close-votes. Actually, I've reversed my downvote completely (+1).

Comment: The following might be of interest. Let $A$ and $B$ be subgroups of relatively prime orders $m$ and $n$, respectively, in a finite group $G$. If $G=AB$ and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $H=(A \cap H)(B \cap H)$.

And one more. If $G=AB$, where $A$, $B$ are abelian subgroups, then $Z(G) = (A \cap Z(G))(B \cap Z(G))$.

Comment: For the second result, relatively prime is necessary? Can you give the proof?

Comment: You don't need coprimality for the second one, no. The proof is not difficult. Give it a shot and if you can't do it I'll write one down a little later. (One containment is trivial, so you only need to work a little to prove the other containment.)